# is it possible to send string array with SOAP message in objective c during web service method call?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, string, soap

i want to call web service method and method signature is :

public string getPath(string[ ] PathArray); // csharp

and in xcode i have to write soap message for that.
i know how to send the single string value but string array i dont know

to access the webservice method i have to send PathArray.

i hope some one know how to send string Array with SOAP message in objective c

thank you in advance

Comment: Suggestion: Write another web service method that _returns_ a .net string array (with 2 or more items in the array) and call that method from the iPhone app.  The xml format that you get the string array in is probably the same format you should send it in to the getPath method.

Comment: W3 defines that standard, check out: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383522

Comment: thank you i will read this documents